# My function won't work on a column in the dataframe, but works in an isolated setting

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I successfully converted the column 'genres' into a list or array of strings. However, there is a " " in position 0 for each word after a comma.

Example: 
**["David", " Bob", " Catherine"]**

I then created the function below to deal with this issue.

```
def remove_leading_space(array):
  new_arr = []
  for word in array:
    if (word[0] == " "):
        word = word[1:]
    new_arr.append(word)
  return new_arr
```

This function works for the example above as well as designated cells like so.

```
print(remove_leading_space(df['genres'][1])
```

But, when I do the following code:

```
#Remove the leading spaces 
df['genres'] = df['genres'].apply(lambda x: remove_leading_space(x))
```

I get an error stating **string index out of range** , and points towards **word[0]**. Once again, this code works for any

```
df['genres'][x].
```

**UPDATE:**

I followed Anton's advice and rewrote my function to the following:

```
def remove_leading_space(array):
new_arr = []
for word in array:
    new_arr.append(word.lstrip(" "))
return new_arr
```

It works. Thanks Anton. Also @piRSquared made a novel suggestion I'll use in the future.

Comment: Try: df['genres'] = df['genres'].str.lstrip(). Or wait.. is it a list?

Comment: Likely a function of your data being separated by `', '` or comma spaces.  You'll want to split on `', '` or do what @AntonvBR suggested.

Comment: @piRSquared what a novel idea! I fixed my function to Anton's method and it works.

Comment: df['genres'].where(df['genres'].str.slice(0,1)!=' ',df['genres'].str.slice(1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have arrays, e.g.:

```
                    genres
0  [David, Bob, Catherine]
```

Do:

```
import pandas as pd  
data = {'genres':[["David", " Bob", " Catherine"]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.genres = df.genres.apply(lambda x: [i.lstrip() for i in x])

print(df.values)
```

Returns:

```
[[list(['David', 'Bob', 'Catherine'])]] # leading space is removed
```

---

**And** if you have strings, e.g.:

```
       genres
0       David
1         Bob
2   Catherine
```

Do:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'genres':["David", " Bob", " Catherine"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.genres = df.genres.str.lstrip()

print(df.values) # leading space is removed
```

Returns:

```
[['David']
 ['Bob']
 ['Catherine']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing here is that the apply function will pass the arguments one-by-one, not as an array. Your function is designed to take in an array, so it treats each string like an array and breaks it up into characters. You just need to rewrite the remove_leaving_space function to take a single word, not an array, then you can use it as you suggest here.

As an aside, you don't need to use lambda to reference your function - you can pass the function directly to apply and it will work just fine

```
def remove_leading_space(word):
    if (word[0] == " "):
        word = word[1:]
    return word

df['genres'] = df['genres'].apply(remove_leading_space)
```